# iOS 8.1 textfield delegate is not reaching while using Siri

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

UITextfiled delegate "ShouldChangeCharactersInRange" is not getting Called while using siri in iOS8 or later, however it is working in older version of iOS.

As our app need to manipulate the text,this feature is not working with ios8. I could not find any new methods in uitextfield to support this. Any idea?

Comment: It seems to be related to the fact that iOS 8 now features real-time dictation.